# Modify ManyToMany with different users

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I have the models

**Foo: models.py**

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**Bar: models.py**

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
user_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_list')
foo_list = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

I made my own user admin site for bar objects.

**admin.py**

```
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Bar
    form = BarForm

    def __init__(self, model, user_admin_site):
        self.form.user_admin_site = user_admin_site 
        super(BarAdmin, self).__init__(model, user_admin_site)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(BarAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = request.user
        return form

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            pass
        else:
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()

    user_admin_site = UserAdmin(name='usersadmin')

    user_admin_site.register(Foo)
    user_admin_site.register(Bar, BarAdmin)
```

I have a custom form to add Foos to a Bar.

**forms.py**

```
class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo_list'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Foo.objects.filter(user=self.current_user))
        rel = ManyToOneRel(Foo, 'id')
        self.fields['foo_list'].widget = RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(self.fields['foo_list'].widget, rel, self.user_admin_site)

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        exclude = ['owner']
```

Users can only see and edit Bars that they are on the user list for. When I add Foos to a Bar as the admin from the default admin site, everything works fine (adding a Foo puts another Foo in foo_list). However, if two users try to add to the foo list, only the second one will save their Foo(s) to the list (adding Foo(s) makes foo_list contain only the added Foo(s)). Is there something wrong with how this is structured, or is there a way to make it so that multiple users can add to the ManyToManyField?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overwriting foo_list every time the form is saved.  You'd need to use some kind of custom save logic to add the new foo objects to the old ones rather than replacing them.

You could create your own form that's not a modelform, and provide a selectmultiple field (or whatever), and then on save, do `bar.foo_list.add(foo)`

edit: I meant for each foo that's returned from the form field, do `bar.foo_list.add(foo)`

edit2: I wanted to leave this as a comment, but the formatting is restrictive.  You said it works if you're an admin?  Do you see all the foo objects or just the ones you created?  Let's say this is all foo objects, with the ones in foo_list checked:

```
[ ] myfoo1
[x] myfoo2
[ ] myfoo3
[ ] otherfoo1
[x] otherfoo2
```

If a user only sees:

```
[ ] myfoo1
[x] myfoo2
[ ] myfoo3
```

then when they save it, the foo_list will only store the checked values from that list.  If as an admin, you see the whole list (either it's not filtered, or you created all the foos *as* that user), then everything should work as expected.

Comment: I'm going to dig into the main admin site code to see if that's what it does (since it works if I'm the admin).

Comment: Yes, your description is what's happening. As an admin, I can see all Foo objects that can be added to a Bar regardless of who created it. As a user, you can only see Foo objects that you created. So I guess my question is whether or not there's a way to make users be able to add to the relation with a restricted set of choices.